# How to find a root when FindRoot refuses

Tags: equation-solving

After empirically setting x = 960, I find that

```
Total@Table[
   If[(v/x)[[i]] > Sqrt[Floor[(v/x)[[i]]] Ceiling[(v/x)[[i]]]], 
   Ceiling[(v/x)[[i]]], Floor[(v/x)[[i]]]], {i, Length[v]}] - s
```

equals 0 for `s=26` and `v = {9061, 7179, 5259, 3319, 1182}`

So I was expecting that

```
FindRoot[Total@Table[
   If[(v/x)[[i]] > Sqrt[Floor[(v/x)[[i]]] Ceiling[(v/x)[[i]]]], 
   Ceiling[(v/x)[[i]]], Floor[(v/x)[[i]]]], {i, Length[v]}] == s,{x, 1,   Total[v]}]
```

will return  960 but unfortunately, the return is a warning

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.
```

I ask certainly too much to `FindRoot` but is there simple  way to find the expected result algorithmicaly in MA

Comment: See if adding `With[{i = i},...]` works for you:  `...Table[With[{i = i}, If[ ...]],...`

Comment: Any reason why you write `(v/x)[[i]]` instead of `v[[i]]/x`?

Comment: Also, take a look at the output of your first expression: You'll notice that some of the `i`'s are not properly replaced by values. This is because `If` does not evaluate its arguments until the condition can be fully evaluated to `True` or `False`. The suggestion of @MichaelE2 circumvents this by using `With` to insert values into the arguments of `If`

Comment: Many thanks for  both. I have a last question. Why the rule returned is of the form {960-> 959.817}

Comment: `{960 -> 959.817}` looks like you've defined `x = 960` and then used it as a variable in `FindRoot`. Try clearing `x` and see what you get.